# Replacement for <pre> and/or <code> tags?

Tags: html

It appears `<pre>` and `<code>` are ignored by IE8 and FF10. What can I do to display preformatted text?

Comment: Define "ignored." Maybe you're using a reset you forgot about? As Christofian suggests, you probably just don't have anything in your CSS telling them what to look like.

Comment: They're not ignored at all by either browser. Show us how you're using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not ignored. The `<code>` element has nothing to do with preformatted text, but it by default sets the font to monospace. The `<pre>` element works universally. But neither of these elements overrides the normal HTML rule that the `<` character followed by a letter starts a tag; they are not defined to do so, and they do not actually do so in browsers. I suspect a misunderstanding of this is the background to your question.

Thus, within these elements, as elsewhere, to display `<` as data, write `&lt;`, and to display `&` as data, write `&amp;`.

The `<xmp>` element is different. Within it, no markup is recognized, i.e. all characters are shows as-is; the end tag `</xmp>` is recognized, of course. Though this element was deprecated in HTML 3.2 and removed from later specs (though it is mentioned as obsolete in HTML5), it still seems to have support in all browsers. There was also a very similar element, `<listing>`, for wide listings, but support to it has been dropped.